# Difference between MATLAB hough and my implementation

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I am trying to recreate MATLAB's hough function with mine. My code follows

```
function [H,T,R] = my_hough(x,dr,dtheta)
    rows = size(x,1);
    cols = size(x,2);
    D = sqrt((rows - 1)^2 + (cols - 1)^2);
    Nr = 2*(ceil(D/dr)) + 1;
    diagonal = dr*ceil(D/dr);
    R = -diagonal:dr:diagonal;
    T = -90:dtheta:90-dtheta;
    Ntheta = length(T);
    H = zeros(Nr,Ntheta);
    for i = 1:Ntheta
        for n1 = 1:rows
            for n2 = 1:cols
                if x(n1,n2)==1
                    r = n2*cos(T(i)*pi/180) + n1*sin(T(i)*pi/180);
                    [~,j] = min(abs(R-ones(1,Nr)*r));
                    H(j,i) = H(j,i) + 1;
                end
            end
        end    
    end
end
```

where `dr` and `dtheta` are distance and angle resolution. Printing the difference between my Hough table and MATLAB's there are many zeros, but there are also some non-zero elements. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I have not understood completely: the theta array should be decremented by theta, but the rho array not decremented by rho?

Comment: I am not sure about that... I just tried to follow the algorithm described at http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html

Comment: I had no matlab at hand. In octave saying     `T = -90:dtheta:90-dtheta;` gives you an array up to including `90-dtheta` (as in the given link). With `dtheta = 1` for example, it is `[-90, -89, ..., 88, 89];`

Comment: Same in matlab, but I don't see your point...

Comment: It's supposed to be −90°≤θ<90°, which results in -90:89. That can be achieved via `T = -90:dtheta:90;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually it was a very silly mistake...

```
r = n2*cos(T(i)*pi/180) + n1*sin(T(i)*pi/180);
```

must be

```
r = (n2-1)*cos(T(i)*pi/180) + (n1-1)*sin(T(i)*pi/180);
```

Thanks to this weird MATLAB indexing.

Comment: In addition, you can either eliminate the conversion to radians using `cosd()` and `sind()` or use `degtorad()` to convert degrees to radians which makes for cleaner code.